# Variable that chooses between two async functions in rust - incompatible arm types

Tags: rust, rust-actix, rust-async-std

I have a variable that will control which function is the default behavior of my web app, but both functions are `async` and it wont let me because they're different closures. Something like this reproduces the same error:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=db0269ef4852a94438e6d4925ca83d3b

Now my questions are:

- How do I solve this so that the match works?
- Is there a better way to set default server behavior programatically on actix based on user CLI flags? For context, this is more or less what I have:

`main.rs`

```
// Matches comes from the command line
let a = match matches.occurrences_of("default"){
        1 => handlers::forward,
        _ => handlers::resource_not_found,
    };

... setting up db, auth etc

HttpServer::new(move || {
            App::new()
            ... lots of routes 
            .default_service(web::route().to(a))
```

`handlers.rs`

```
pub async fn resource_not_found(
) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
   Ok(HttpResponse::NotFound().body("Resource does not exist"))
}
pub async fn forward(
) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
   Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().body("Resource does exist"))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I solve this so that the match works

You can create two closures that both return a boxed future, and coerce them to a function pointer:

```rust
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::future::Future;

let a: fn() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<HttpResponse, Error>>>> =
    match matches.occurrences_of("default") {
        1 => || Box::pin(handlers::forward()),
        _ => || Box::pin(handlers::resource_not_found()),
    };
```

If the functions really are that simple, then you can avoid the boxing and return `std::future::Ready`:

```rust
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::future::{Future, Ready, ready};

let a: fn() -> Ready<Result<HttpResponse, Error>> =
    match matches.occurrences_of("default") {
        1 => || handlers::forward,
        _ => || handlers::resource_not_found,
    };

// handlers.rs

pub fn resource_not_found(
) -> Ready<Result<HttpResponse, Error>> {
   ready(Ok(HttpResponse::NotFound().body("Resource does not exist")))
}

pub fn forward(
) -> Ready<Result<HttpResponse, Error>> {
   ready(Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().body("Resource does exist")))
}
```

> Is there a better way to set default server behavior programmatically on actix based on user CLI flags

You could do the matching *inside* a new handler instead of outside:

```rust
let x = matches.occurrences_of("default");
let a = move || async move {
    match x {
        1 => handlers::forward().await,
        _ => handlers::resource_not_found().await,
    }
};
```

Now instead of an extra allocation and dynamic dispatch per call, you just have to match on an integer.